# Converting a python file into a JS file

Tags: javascript, python, windows, pyjamas

I've been trying to figure out how to convert python files into JavaScript files.

I downloaded the latest pyjamas and I installed it in my c:\Python26\Lib\site-packages folder. I'm running Python 2.6 on Windows 7.

Comment: that project hasn't been updated in over 2 years, I wouldn't use it if I were you...

Comment: @MattDMo: Really? I see a commit from 15 days ago in their GitHub repository.

Comment: What other alternatives to pyjamas would you refer?

Comment: @icktoofay Oh, I was looking at PyPI...

Comment: As a start, try reading some documentation? Here's an online book. http://pyjs.org/book/Bookreader.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you should be able to translate a Python file to JavaScript like so:

```
python -m pyjs.pyjampiler -w directory/of/source -r main.py -o /output/path.js
```

Comment: or just `pyjsbuild main.py` where the folder containing the .py files are in the `site-packages/pyjs/` directory